# Laravel return object with nesting

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Assume the following models:

```
class Character extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['items'];
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function items(){
        return $this->hasMany("App\Item");
    }
}

class Item extends Model
{

    public function character(){
        return $this->belongsTo("App\Character");
    }

}
```

When a request is made, the controller performs the following:

```
public function getCharacter(Request $request, $characterID = 0){

        $characters = array(Character::find($characterID));

        foreach($characters as $key => $value){
            //ADD THE ITEMS
            $characters[$key]->items = $characters[$key]->items;
        }
        return $characters;
    }
```

------**This works fine.**

Im getting a character json with a member "items" that holds all the data for the corresponding item models.

**However**, assume `Items` didnt belong to `Character` but to `ItemPackage`. Specifically, `Items` belong to `ItemPackage` ( `ItemPackage` has many `Items` ) and `ItemPackage` belongs to `Character` ( `Character` has many `ItemPackage`(s) )

In a similar fashion, i tried performing the following in the controller but it doesnt work.

```
....
foreach($characters as $key => $value){
    //ADD THE ITEM
    $characters[$key]->itemPackages = $characters[$key]->itemPackages
    //the above line works but we also need to add the item obj data so:
        foreach($characters[$key]->itemPackages as $key2){
            $characters[$key]->itemPackages[$key]->arrayOfItems = "whatever here";
        }
    }
....
```

Specifically, i get an error  of : Undefined offset: 1. Im clearly not understanding the data structures im operating on very well, maybe someone could illuminate me.

Thanks for taking the time

Comment: Either I don't get something here, or you can simply do this in the first place `public function getCharacter(Request $request, $characterID = 0){
        return Character::where('id', $characterID)->get();
    }` what I mean by that is, your foreach does actually nothing :) and this part `$characters[$key]->items = $characters[$key]->items;` is pointless.

Comment: If i remove '$characters[$key]->items = $characters[$key]->items;' i get the character object and its data but it has no field "items" in which an array of item resides now. Getting a Character model on its own , even though relationships exist doesnt mean it will bring all the relationship objects in the response

Answer (score 0):

A solution to this would be :

```
$characters = Character::with('itemPackages')->with("itemPackages.items")->get();
```